# How can I make a color wheel using CSS (with white at center and fading to black at the rim)?

Tags: html, css, colors, gradient

The code below produces this color wheel, which is close to what I want but not quite:

[image: color wheel]

How can I adjust the CSS so that the color wheel contains all hues (such as via `conic-gradient`, and maybe I've done this correctly already) *and* each hue transitions from full lightness (white) at the center to 0 lightness (black) at the edge?

By "lightness" I mean the L value in HSL color codes.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient */

.radial {
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, hsl(0deg 0% 100% / 100%), hsl(0deg 0% 100% / 50%), hsl(0deg 0% 100% / 0%), hsl(0deg 0% 0% / 0%), hsl(0deg 0% 0% / 100%));
}


/* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/conic-gradient */

.conic {
  background: conic-gradient(hsl(0deg 100% 50%), hsl(10deg 100% 50%), hsl(20deg 100% 50%), hsl(30deg 100% 50%), hsl(40deg 100% 50%), hsl(50deg 100% 50%), hsl(60deg 100% 50%), hsl(70deg 100% 50%), hsl(80deg 100% 50%), hsl(90deg 100% 50%), hsl(100deg 100% 50%), hsl(110deg 100% 50%), hsl(120deg 100% 50%), hsl(130deg 100% 50%), hsl(140deg 100% 50%), hsl(150deg 100% 50%), hsl(160deg 100% 50%), hsl(170deg 100% 50%), hsl(180deg 100% 50%), hsl(190deg 100% 50%), hsl(200deg 100% 50%), hsl(210deg 100% 50%), hsl(220deg 100% 50%), hsl(230deg 100% 50%), hsl(240deg 100% 50%), hsl(250deg 100% 50%), hsl(260deg 100% 50%), hsl(270deg 100% 50%), hsl(280deg 100% 50%), hsl(290deg 100% 50%), hsl(300deg 100% 50%), hsl(310deg 100% 50%), hsl(320deg 100% 50%), hsl(330deg 100% 50%), hsl(340deg 100% 50%), hsl(350deg 100% 50%));
}
```

```html
<div class="conic" />
<div class="radial" />
```

Currently my `radial-gradient` isn't smooth from center to edge.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/conic-gradient

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient

Comment: hello, unsure if that could do but here is 2 hints : start/stop value from black to transparent with both gradient together or mix-blend-mode  https://jsfiddle.net/dwjq0rsb/ (third is the image itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use blend modes like this:

```
.radial {
  background: radial-gradient(closest-edge, #fff, #000);
  mix-blend-mode: luminosity; // Tells the browser to use the luminosity values from this gradient
}

.conic {
  background: conic-gradient(hsl(0deg 100% 50%), hsl(10deg 100% 50%), hsl(20deg 100% 50%), hsl(30deg 100% 50%), hsl(40deg 100% 50%), hsl(50deg 100% 50%), hsl(60deg 100% 50%), hsl(70deg 100% 50%), hsl(80deg 100% 50%), hsl(90deg 100% 50%), hsl(100deg 100% 50%), hsl(110deg 100% 50%), hsl(120deg 100% 50%), hsl(130deg 100% 50%), hsl(140deg 100% 50%), hsl(150deg 100% 50%), hsl(160deg 100% 50%), hsl(170deg 100% 50%), hsl(180deg 100% 50%), hsl(190deg 100% 50%), hsl(200deg 100% 50%), hsl(210deg 100% 50%), hsl(220deg 100% 50%), hsl(230deg 100% 50%), hsl(240deg 100% 50%), hsl(250deg 100% 50%), hsl(260deg 100% 50%), hsl(270deg 100% 50%), hsl(280deg 100% 50%), hsl(290deg 100% 50%), hsl(300deg 100% 50%), hsl(310deg 100% 50%), hsl(320deg 100% 50%), hsl(330deg 100% 50%), hsl(340deg 100% 50%), hsl(350deg 100% 50%));
}
```

[image: Color wheel]

This will give you a *mathematically* smooth colour wheel, however it doesn’t appear *visually* smooth because HSL isn’t perceptually uniform.

You might explore using LCH as an alternative approach: https://lea.verou.me/2020/04/lch-colors-in-css-what-why-and-how/

Comment: Wow, this is super interesting. I'm excited to look into this. Thank you!

Comment: I liked reading about LCH and will read about it more for the future. As for the blend modes, they don't quite lead to what I'm hoping for. If you notice your screenshot, the edge isn't black. The colors do get darker _toward_ the edge (especially in the green area), but what I'm looking for is pure white in the center and 1 pixel of pure black at the rim. So within those 2 dimensions, we'll see hue and lightness represented. I can then use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EyeDropper to pick a color. Separately, in a 1-dimensional slider I'll allow adjusting saturation. Thanks!

Comment: If you add `closest-edge` to the gradient, it will reach black at the edge of the circle rather than at the corners of the clipped background  area… I’ve updated my answer to show this. Still not exactly as desired. I think you’d have to have multiple luminosity gradients layered on, each adjusted to compensate for the hue it was laid over.

Comment: By the way, have you considered using `<input type=“color” />` for this? (If so, would be interested to know why you didn’t go for it.)

Comment: You led me to read about LCH, which has been really interesting. I plan to figure out how to import these components (or create something like them, since this particular repo doesn't look easy to use): https://oklch.evilmartians.io/#66.23,0.038,90.9,100 So I'll go ahead and mark your answer as accepted because even though it doesn't answer my actual question, you helped me at the goal level, which is better.

Comment: Awesome! Would love to see the final result when you get there :-)